# Django single query to count & use data on for loop?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I need to display total count & also use the queryset to loop on the template ! But the thing is its causing two queries to do this, is there any efficient way to manage this on single query ?

```
data = Data.objects.filter(pk=pk)
count = data.count // 1st query

and then using data to iterate over loop on template // this makes second query
```

Is there any other best way to do the same thing or it needs these two queries for sure ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `len` on the queryset to force the evaluation and at the same time be able to get the count. This will prevent hitting the database again when you iterate through the same queryset:

```py
data = Data.objects.filter(pk=pk)
#  Hits the db and evaluates data
count = len(data) 

#  Will not hit the db again
for d in data: 
    print(d)
```

This should end up with just one query.

Comment: But it will affect the performance, if its a large set of data right ?

Comment: Yes but I think since you are going to iterate through it in the template, its still going to affect the performance anyway

Comment: ya but, i can paginate and send to template, so that wont be a matter !

Comment: So you want to count just the page or the whole thing? If the whole thing, then I think you will need the separate `count()` call